# How to set a numbercolumn's value on combobox change?

Tags: extjs, combobox, listener

I have a [grid panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMZn8.png). Its records contain a **numberfield** and a **combobox**. Combobox holds currencies. What I want to do is to **set exchange rate value to 1 when currency selected as Euro**.

[image: Grid Panel]

I added this listener but it didn't work:

```
listeners : 
{
    select : function (combo, record, index)
    {
        if(record.getDisplayValue() == "€")
            Ext.getCmp('exchangeRate').set({value : 1});
    }
}
```

Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this .....

```
Ext.getCmp('exchangeRate').setValue(1);
```

Comment: This is not working well though there are a lot of rows and they're generated at the runtime dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just made a small mistake

```
if(record.getDisplayValue() == "€")
```

"record" in this case is a Ext.data.Model, which doesn't have a method getDisplayValue. You probably mean to use the "combo"

```
if (combo.getDisplayValue() == "€")
```

Comment: Both working same. The main problem is I cannot reach the other fields which are holding exchange rate values.